# Creating counter in pyspark

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark

How to implement the following R code in Pyspark

```
l = data.frame(d=c(1,2,4,7,8,15,17,19,20,25,26,29))
l$d2[1]= 0
l$d3[1]=c=1
for(i in 2:nrow(l))
{ l$d2[i]=l$d[i]-l$d[i-1]
  c= ifelse(l$d2[i]<=3,c,c+1)
  l$d3[i]=c
 }
l
```

I want to iterate through an column and increment a counter if the value if greater than or equal to 3.

eg : Suppose the elements in my column are

1,2,2,3,2,1,5,2,1

Flag should be :
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3

Thanks

Comment: Counter is easy to create, you can use http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.range but for help in rewriting the code you should show your experiments first

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to iterate through an column and increment a counter if the value if greater than or equal to 3.

eg : Suppose the elements in my column are 

1,2,2,3,2,1,5,2,1

Flag should be :
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3

Comment: Hi - i have similar question, how did you solve it in the end? thanks!

Comment: @zhifff : I have added the solution

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the following is the input data.

**Input :**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,'A',1],[2,'A',2],[3,'A',2],[4,'A',3],[5,'A',2],\
                            [6,'A',5],[7,'B',1],[8,'B',2],[9,'B',5],[10,'B',1]],\
                            ['sl_no','partition','value'])
df.show(10)
```

[image: input dataframe]

- **sl_no** - serial number [Basically any column that defines the order of the dataframe]
- **partition** - partition column if the counter needs to be partitioned based on a existing column
- **value** - value based on which counter is incremented

**Output :**

The following code will give you the desired output.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, sum, lit

threshold= 3

df = df.withColumn("greater",when(col("value")>=lit(threshold),1).otherwise(0))\
       .withColumn("counter",sum("greater").over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("sl_no")))\
       .withColumn("partitioned_counter",sum("greater").over(Window.partitionBy(["partition"]).orderBy("sl_no")))\
       .orderBy("sl_no")

df.show(10)
```

[image: output dataframe]

- **sl_no** - serial number [Basically any column that defines the order of the dataframe]
- **partition** - partition column if the counter needs to be partitioned based on a existing column
- **value** - value based on which counter is incremented
- **greater** - check if the value is greater than the threshold [in this case, 3]
- **counter** - counter which increments when the value exceeds the threshold
- **partitioned_counter** - counter which is partitioned by the partition column

If you just need to create an overall counter just based on the order of a column and threshold value, you can use the code used above for creating the **counter** column.

If the use case is to implement the counter separately for a partition column/ set of partition columns, then you can use the code used for creating the **partitioned_counter** column